# Error al agregar evento a un elemento

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de agregar un evento click a 3 elementos. Primer seleccione los 3 elementos con `getElementsByClassName`, después de esto estoy tratando de darle un evento click  a los 3 elementos que ya seleccioné y guardé en la variable `imagenModal`, lo que pasa es que al agregar el evento click me da el siguiente error en consola:

> imagenModal.addEventListeners is not a function

Al dar click quiero que me lance la función `abrirModal`, pero el click me da el error.

```js
let imagenModal = document.getElementsByClassName('imagen');
console.log(imagenModal)
let modalContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-container');


imagenModal.addEventListeners('click', abrirModal);




function abrirModal(){
    console.log(modalContainer);
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor-modal">
   <div class="contenedor">
      <div class="imagen">
         <img src="img/proyecto-cinco.png" >
         <div class="capa">
            <h3><img src="img/lupa2.png" alt="" ></h3>
            <p>Pagina Web - Noticias</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-container">
      <div class="modal modal-close">
         <p class="close">X</p>
         <img src="img/proyecto-cinco.png">
         <div class="modal-textos">
            <h2>Pagina Web - Noticias</h2>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Estás tratando de ejecutar una función en un array, ya que `getElementsByClassName` te devuelve un array, tendrás que recorrer los elementos de este para poder ejecutar el `addEventListener`

Me tomé la libertad de cambiar `getElementsByClassName` por `querySelectorAll`

Resultando lo siguiente:

```js
let imagenModal = document.querySelectorAll('.imagen');
let modalContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-container');

imagenModal.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", abrirModal);
});

function abrirModal(){
    console.log(modalContainer);
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor-modal">
   <div class="contenedor">
      <div class="imagen">
         <img src="img/proyecto-cinco.png" >
         <div class="capa">
            <h3><img src="img/lupa2.png" alt="" ></h3>
            <p>Pagina Web - Noticias</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-container">
      <div class="modal modal-close">
         <p class="close">X</p>
         <img src="img/proyecto-cinco.png">
         <div class="modal-textos">
            <h2>Pagina Web - Noticias</h2>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¡Bien por el `querySelectorAll()` y `forEach()`!